# Aforge.Net wont add frame to VideoFileWriter

Tags: c#, aforge

I'am trying record movie from web camera using Aforge.Net. My code is very simple, and looks like this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private FilterInfoCollection captureDevices;
    private VideoFileWriter videoWriter;
    private VideoCaptureDevice finalVideo;
    private Bitmap videoFrame;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        CameraInit();
    }

    private void CameraInit()
    {
        captureDevices = new FilterInfoCollection(FilterCategory.VideoInputDevice);
        finalVideo = new VideoCaptureDevice(captureDevices[0].MonikerString);
        finalVideo.NewFrame += FinalVideo_NewFrame;
        int cameraCapabilitiesCount = finalVideo.VideoCapabilities.Count();
        VideoCapabilities cameraCapability = finalVideo.VideoCapabilities[cameraCapabilitiesCount - 1];
        videoWriter = new VideoFileWriter();
        videoWriter.Open(@"F:/FilmikiTest/testVideo.mp4", cameraCapability.FrameSize.Width, cameraCapability.FrameSize.Height, cameraCapability.AverageFrameRate, VideoCodec.MPEG4, 5000000);
    }

    private void FinalVideo_NewFrame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        videoFrame = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();
        pictureBox1.Image = videoFrame;
        videoWriter.WriteVideoFrame(videoFrame);
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        finalVideo.Start();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        finalVideo.Stop();
        videoWriter.Close();
    }        
}
```

The problem is after finish recording movie, file is always "empty", there is no any frames. It looks like Aforge in "FinalVideo_NewFrame" event function wont add any frames to videoWriter. Everything should be fine, because i can see that frames in pictureBox1. Do You have any clues what can be wrong with that code?

Answer (score -1):

```
    private void BtnCreateVdo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string Outputpath = @"C:\Users\new\Desktop\Video Result\";
        using (var Vdowriter = new VideoFileWriter())
        {
            Vdowriter.Open(Outputpath + "Vdoresult_Logo.avi", 3856, 2176, 15, VideoCodec.MPEG4, 1000000);
            int ImgId = 1;
            ConvProgress.Value = ImgId;
            foreach (string Fil in Directory.GetFiles(TxtImgDirPath.Text))
            {
                var ImgFilName = Fil;
                using (Bitmap Img = Bitmap.FromFile(Fil) as Bitmap)
                {
                    
                    Vdowriter.WriteVideoFrame(Img);
                    if (ConvProgress.Value < ConvProgress.Maximum)
                    {
                        ConvProgress.Value += 1;
                    }
                }
            }
            Vdowriter.Close();
            Vdowriter.Dispose();
        }
        MessageBox.Show("Video Conversion Completed!", "Info", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).